# What does comparing mean rank mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

Lets assume that I am having 2 samples:

**Sample A**

```
20
20
20
20
25
```

and **Sample B**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

If I want to compare these two samples I can use the `mann-whitney` test. Now, because the 2 samples are not normally distributed, and their distributions do not have the same shape, the `mann-whitney` test will compare the mean ranks.

So what it will do, is rank each observation of each sample. The rank will be the following:

**Sample A**

```
 value  rank
    20  2.5
    20  2.5
    20  2.5
    20  2.5
    25  5
```

and **Sample B**

```
value  rank
    1  1
    2  2
    3  3
    4  4
    5  5
```

Now, both of those samples have the **same mean rank** `(2.5+2.5+2.5+2.5+5)/5` and `(1+2+3+4+5)/5`, but their medians are very different.

Also it seems to me, that two populations of the same size, will always have the same mean rank. Or am I wrong ?

So I do not understand, what is the value of comparing the mean ranks of two populations. Any help ?

Comment: Welcome to CV, quant!

Comment: As an aside: the rank sum test will compare mean ranks **regardless** of the distribution of the data in each group, whether or not they are normal(-ish)ly distributed.

Comment: @Alexis Indeed the mann-whitney is non-parametric, but I thought the mann-whitney compares the medians if the distributions of the two samples have similar shape: https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/kruskal-wallis-h-test-using-spss-statistics.php

Comment: It also compares the means of the *data* (not the ranks) if the population distributions of both groups have the same shape *and* the same variance. But those are some pretty additional strong assumptions (and your samples A & B  certainly do not look like equal shapes or variances, for example). The fundamental null hypothesis, regardless of distribution, is that neither group is "stochastically larger": $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }P(X_{A} > X_B) = 0.5$ with $\text{H}_{0}\text{: }P(X_{A} > X_B) \ne 0.5$.

Comment: Whoops! Small correction in my previous comment, the second hypothesis should be labeled $\text{H}_{\text{A}}$. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**When comparing two independent samples, you want to rank *all the data* together.**

Revising your example:

**Sample A**

```
 value  rank
    20  7.5
    20  7.5
    20  7.5
    20  7.5
    25  10
```

and **Sample B**

```
value  rank
    1  1
    2  2
    3  3
    4  4
    5  5
```

**What is going on?**

Sample B's value of 1 is the lowest ordered value **from *both* samples**, so it gets a rank of 1. Similarly for Sample B's values of 2–5. The mean rank for Sample B is therefore $\frac{1+2+3+4+5}{5}=2.5$.

Sample A's values of 20, 20, 20, and 20 occupy the 6th, 7th, 8th, and 9th ranks together, so they each get the average rank of $\frac{6+7+8+9}{4\text{ rank positions}}=7.5$. Finally, Sample A's value of 10 is the largest value **from *both* samples** so it gets the highest rank 10. The mean rank for Sample A is therefore $\frac{7.5+7.5+7.5+7.5+10}{5}=8$.

**Bonus:** To be super explicit: **No. The mean ranks of two independent samples of the same $\boldsymbol{N}$ will *not* necessarily have the same mean ranks.**